# Decorating $stateProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to implement my own `cssUrl` parameter in a state definition (akin to ui-router-styles).

I am aware that ui-router's `$stateProvider` can be decorated through its `decorator` method, but how can I add the builder function for `cssUrl` in a config block of my main module that has dependent modules that define their own states (which means those dependent modules' config block run **before** the main config block, and therefore have no access to the decorated `$stateProvider`)
?

Right now I'm accomplishing this through a `$stateChangeSuccess` event, but I wanted to do it using the `decorator`.

Comment: you can try run block

Comment: run block runs after the config block, and I can't inject $stateProvider there